# Binary Tree Using PHP & MySQL that creates 5 children and 25 grandchildren from registered members

Tags: php, mysql

Am working on a project that needs to create children and grandchildren using a root ID

It works in this way
user_1 registers himself, he(user_1) also  registers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and have total(maximum) of 5 children
user_2 registers 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
user_3 registers 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
and so on

ON user_1's profile a tree table lists out his children and from his children,
the grandchildren he has from each of the registered children is also displayed.

```
                                   1
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |                  |               |                |
     2                3                  4               5                6
---------------     ---------------   ---------------  ------------   -------------- 
|   |   |  |  |     |   |   |  |  |   |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |   |   |
7   8   9  10 11    12  13 14 15  16  17 18  19 20 21  22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  31
```

The User_ID's would not necessarily be in order but just an example
Then also, **USER 1** would see the total of children and grandchildren he has 
The maximum of Children = 5, grandchildren = 20 == (25)

I have created a table like this

```
 id | name  | password | totalfamily | grandparent | parent_id
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would want the table to be hold info like this the one below

```
id | name  | password | totalfamily | grandparent | parent_id
1     jon     ******                  NULL          NULL
2     mel     ******                  NULL          1
3     al      ******                  NULL          1
4     me      ******                  1             3
```

if there is need for new table structure to make it work, that will be ok too.

I have done the procedures for registration(including checking for the parent_id and grandparent_id) and the logging in

But am in a fix concerning how to QUERY the database to help me list out the names like a tree structure to show the children and the grandchildren

I know it needs complex querying statements to execute

I am in urgent need of solving this(hope it doesn't break the rules) as I have spent days reading Hierarchical data structuring tutorials for my Mysql+PHP yet none seems easy to be heading my direction.

Help anyone???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just created table with id,name parent_id

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | parent_id |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | one    |      NULL |
|  2 | two    |         1 |
|  3 | three  |         1 |
|  4 | four   |         2 |
|  5 | five   |         2 |
|  6 | six    |         2 |
|  7 | seven  |         2 |
|  8 | eight  |         3 |
|  9 | nine   |         3 |
| 10 | ten    |         3 |
| 11 | eleven |         3 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

and when user 1 want to get all the child. Query will like this

```
select * from users where parent_id in(select id from users where parent_id = 1) or parent_id = 1;
```

I think it may help you

Comment: It was useful in getting the children of a particular parent

Answer (score 0):

```
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
| id | name   | parent_id |grandparentID
+----+--------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | one    |      NULL |     NULL   |
|  2 | two    |         1 |     NULL   |
|  3 | three  |         1 |      1     |
|  4 | four   |         2 |      1     |
|  5 | five   |         2 |      2     |
|  6 | six    |         2 |      2     |
|  7 | seven  |         2 |      2     |
|  8 | eight  |         3 |      3     |
|  9 | nine   |         3 |      2     |
| 10 | ten    |         3 |      1     |
| 11 | eleven |         3 |      2     |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

That's how I factored it to be.

And in the page that lists the children out this is how I got it.

```
                     Normal_codes
                          |
    ---newman ---ukwangwa ---hello ---azonto
```

using the following codes

```
        function display_tree() {  
$result = $this->qry("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Parent='?' or Parent ='?';" ,
 'in(select id from user_id from users where Parent = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'")', $_SESSION['id']);
      //select * from users where parent_id in(select id from users where parent_id = 1) or parent_id = 1;  

         echo '<div align="center">'.$_SESSION['name'].'<br></div>';
         echo '<div align="center">|</div>';
           echo '<div align="center">';
          while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
               echo "\n\r---".$row['name'];
              $result1 = $this->qry("SELECT * FROM users WHERE grandParent='?' or grandParent ='?';" ,
 'in(select user_id from users where grandParent = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'")', $_SESSION['id']);
             while( $row1 =mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                //echo "<br>--".$row1['name'];  
             }
          }; 
          echo '</div>';

    }
```

anyone got an idea as to any HTML, Javascript/Jquery Code that can help me to list the children and grandchildren out in a tree form.

```
                             Normal_codes
                                  |
       ---newman ---     ukwangwa     ---  hello     ---    azonto
            |                |               |               |
   n1 n2  n3 n4 n5 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5   h1 h2 h3 h4 h4    a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
```

The initials being the children registered by each of the five parents

Any PHP code to aid me in the querying will also be appreciated.